# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycryptodome'

Tags: python, encryption, protocols

```
import pycryptodome
```

and get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycryptodome'
```

I've been getting this error every time I try import "pycryptodome" however it is definitely installed. I've tried uninstalling and installing again but still get the same error. Used pip to install and using python version 3.8.5.

Seen many people getting the same error however it is very specific to that module import.

Comment: Could you add your import statement?

Comment: Make sure you use correct pip to install the package. Try installing with `python3.8 -m pip install pycryptodome` and try to import again.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-10-55c783174396>", line 1
    python3.8 -m pip install pycryptodome
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Get this error when I try that command
@xmantas